# move_uploaded_file is not fetching path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my controller

```
    public function createAdmin()
     {
        
        $photo=$_FILES['bannerPic']['name'];
        $tempname=$_FILES['bannerPic']['tmp_name'];

        // echo $tempname." ".$photo;
        move_uploaded_file($tempname, 'picture/banner/'.$photo);

        $data=[
        'sliderPic' => $photo,
        ];

        dd($data);
        // \App\Models\Banner::create($data);
        // return view('Banner');
    }
```

here is my route

```
    Route::post('/BannerEdit', [App\Http\Controllers\BannerController::class, 
    'createAdmin']);
```

here is my blade form

```
    <form action="{{ url('') }}/BannerEdit" method="post" class="col-12" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf

     <div class="mb-3 col-12">                                            
        <label class="col-4 text-label form-label">Banner Photo*</label>                                            
        <input type="file" name="bannerPic" class="form-control input-rounded col-4 mb-3" 
         required>                                                                            
     </div>                  
     <div class="mb-3 text-end">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
     </div>                                        
  </form>
```

When i submit the data it Gives me an Error as

move_uploaded_file(picture/banner/favicon.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

But this Directory Exists

And i checked with full pathof localhost then it does not supports http path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use getcwd() function like this:

**$dirpath = realpath(dirname(getcwd()));**

So your controller code will be:

```
public function createAdmin()
     {
        
        $photo=$_FILES['bannerPic']['name'];
        $tempname=$_FILES['bannerPic']['tmp_name'];

        // echo $tempname." ".$photo;
        $dirpath = realpath(dirname(getcwd()));
        move_uploaded_file($tempname, $dirpath.'/'.$photo);

        $data=[
        'sliderPic' => $photo,
        ];

        dd($data);
        // \App\Models\Banner::create($data);
        // return view('Banner');
    }
```

let me know if it works.. if not then we'll modify $dirpath variable

**PS:** this solution will work on server. are you working on server or in localhost?

**EDIT:**

Other solution is to use below function to get proper directory structure:

```
$dirpath = public_path('picture/banner/');
```

Comment: I am Working on localhost

Comment: @YashBohra i've added another solution in answer.. that will work

Comment: public_path is working..... thank you sir